# Android mediaPlayer Error (-1003,0) not documented

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am playing around with streaming video from a home server in an android app. I am using a simple VideoView for this and it is working fine on my galaxy note.

The problem is when I try to run it on my rockchip MK908 (android tv box) I get the "cannot play this video" message. When I implement the onError(MediaPlayer,what,extra) for the videoview I get:

what = -1003
extra = 0

I looked at the MediaPlayer class' constants for this error but there is none with the value -1003. I have also been google-ing and haven't found any reference to this number.

Can anyone offer any insight to this error value or point me in some useful direction?

To play videos I am simply passing the URL as a string, e.g.

```
videoView.setVideoPath("http://192.168.2.81/...")
```

Comment: can you please write down the code that you have used?

Answer (score 3):

That error is "cannot connect". You can find it [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/135936072b24b090fb63940aea41b408d855a4f3/include/media/stagefright/MediaErrors.h).